# Confidence interval for naive bayes estimation

Tags: confidence-interval, estimation, naive-bayes

I have some simple model with 2 independent input variables A,B . I want to calculate some probability.
$$
    P(X|a,b) = P(a,b|X) P(X) / P(a,b)    \\ 
    P(X|a,b) =  P(a|X) P(b|X) * P(X) / ( P(a) * P(b) )   \\
    ... \\\
    P(X|a,b) =  P(X|a) P(X|b) / P(X)
$$

all probabilities from the right side can be estimated , using for example [wilson confidence interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Wilson_score_interval) for ratios.

My question is how to estimate confidence interval for $P(X|a,b)$ - actually product of 3 distributions. $1/P(a|X) , P(b|X) , P(X)$

Comment: Simplest would be to bootstrap. You've got a ratio distribution there, and it isn't Cauchy.

Comment: Naive Bayes doesn't have to be Bayesian so the answer depends on whether or not it is.  Since you used the phrase "confidence interval," I am presuming you meant that you were using a null hypothesis method and @generic_user user is correct bootstrap would be simplest.  If you are not, then you should probably use the Metropolis-Hasting algorithm as it can be made very flexible if need be.